# Rails - passing multiple params to a form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form_tag that I'm using for a search. I need to pass not only the :term (what is being searched for), but also the :ques_num parameter. Currently, :ques_num is not being passed in.

```
<%= form_tag display_questions_path(:ques_num => 2), method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :term, params[:term], placeholder: "Search Terms..." %>
<% end %>
```

This directs me to the address with the :term passed in, but not :ques_num. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [hidden_field_tag](https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.1.7/ActionView%2FHelpers%2FFormTagHelper:hidden_field_tag) instead:

```
<%= form_tag display_questions_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :term, params[:term], placeholder: "Search Terms..." %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :ques_num, 2 %>
<% end %>
```